# Get total hours from timestamp

Tags: timestamp, google-sheets

How can I get the total hours from a timestamp of 28:00 hours?  or any hours over 24....

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5pSEjxJvt_1SWh5ZTVQS25aX00/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-xX8WLXg4hHvdhmts5GWn_Q
There's an image of it.

Comment: The link isn't shared with anyone with link

Comment: @Rubén fixed--though this question is 8 years old :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I figured it out.  If you change the formatting of it to just do normal instead of hours, it will output a value like 1.16666....  That value is a integer representation of the day.  So 1.66666...*24 hours in a day = total number of hours.

So for my example I'm trying to calculate the total amount of money I've made.  28:00 represents the hours I've worked.  So say 28:00 is in cell H3 and say I make $20 an hour.

```
=H3*24*20
```

That formula will give me the total amount of money I've made so far.  Hope that helps someone.